# Element-wise matrix vector multiplication

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor *m* which stores *n* `3 x 3` matrices with dim `n x 3 x 3` and a tensor *v* with *n* `3x1` vectors and dim `n x 3`. How can I apply element-wise matrix-vector multiplication, i.e. multiply the *i*-th matrix with the *i*-th vector, to get an output tensor with dim `n x 3`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to perform a matrix multiplication operation ([`__matmul__`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html)) in a batch-wise manner. Intuitively you can use the batch-matmul operator [`torch.bmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bmm.html). Keep in mind you first need to unsqueeze one dimension on `v` such that it becomes a 3D tensor. In this case indexing the last dimension with `None` as `v[..., None]` will provide a shape of `(n, 3, 1)`.

With `torch.bmm`:

```
>>> torch.bmm(m, v[..., None])
```

As it turns out, `torch.matmul` handles this case out-of-the-box:

```
>>> torch.matmul(m, v[..., None]) # same as m@v[..., None]
```

If you want explicit control over the operation, you can go with [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html):

```
>>> torch.einsum('bij,bj->bi', m, v)
```